# ssh is ok, but connection refused when trying to rsync, why?

Tags: rsync, configuration

Editing the question, sorry for the confusion

I need make cron job that will backup a directory that resides on a remote server, have the backup on the machine running the cron job. The remote server doesn't have rsync this is why I am doing this this way.

The remote server name is athens, and the directory I want to backup is /disk3/nicolas/scripts

The only connection allowed is ssh, which works. I initiate this command to copy the SRC (athens::disk3/nicolas/scripts/) to current directory

```
rsync --verbose athens::disk3/nicolas/scripts/ .

rsync: failed to connect to athens: Connection refused (61)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-40/rsync/clientserver.c(105) [receiver=2.6.9]
```

Is there something I need to edit on the remote server? inetd.conf perhaps?

As asked, I'm using rsync version 2.6.9. There is no -e option to force ssh, in my version of rsync, the -e option is to specify the remote shell to use. I can not increase more verbosity.

Comment: I'm confused, I would expect something like 'rsync -vvv -e ssh athens:/disk3/nicolas/scripts/ ./`.  `-e` always takes an argument for the transport protocol you want to use.  Also what's up with the double :: after athens?

Comment: I guess I don't understand well how rsync works. I will edit my question, sorry for that

Comment: You've definitely got rsync installed on the remote host right?

Comment: no, rsync not installed on remote server, does it have to?

Comment: Yes, you need to have rsync installed at both ends - that combined with the correct syntax supplied by @Jona and you should be closer.

Comment: Ok thanks to all for your help, I understand better now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try verbose mode in rsync by adding `-vvv` to see where it is failing.

Are you using a very old version of rsync that doesn't default to using ssh (older than 2.6.0)? If so, try adding `-e ssh` to force ssh mode.

Please edit your question and paste your debug output and the exact rsync command line you are trying to run.

Answer (score 2):

You say:

> The only connection allowed is ssh

When trying to use the rsync daemon as opposed to rsync over ssh you need to open tcp port 873 and ensure that the rsyncd is running on the remote machine.

In this case I suspect you actually want to do rsync over ssh in which case changing the double :: to a single : may well be enough to achieve this:

```
rsync -v athens:/disk3/nicolas/scripts/ .
```

Something like the above might do it, you'll need a single : and to specify a valid path.